# XLDeploy get .net dependencies from nuget feeds

Tags: tfs, nuget, nexus, xl-deploy

I would like to create a dar file for a .net Project. I don't want to put all dependency to dar package. I have pack all dependency as nuget package and push them to nuget feed on TFS. I would like to use packages from nuget feeds, I don't want to directly put them in dar file. But, I could not find how to put reference for nuget packages which are located in tfs feeds.

Example: published nuget artifacts to tfs feed
[image]

In java, You can do same thing with maven/nexus. You can publish packages to nexus and you can use file URI of the packages in deployit-manifest.xml which are in nexus. You don't have to put artifacts directly into dar file. There is an example below.

```
<file.File name="common">
  <targetFileName>common.jar</targetFileName>
  <targetPath>/target/path/</targetPath>
  <createTargetPath>true</createTargetPath>
  <fileUri>maven:com.acme.temp:common:jar:4.0.0</fileUri>
</file.File>
```

Is there a similar approach nuget/tfs feeds for .net projects.

Comment: How did you created the dar file?Through TFS or locally? Did you just mean you want to use package which are located in tfs feeds as a reference  package  for your dar package?

Comment: I have created the dar file via TFS. Yes, I mean that.

Comment: The deployment package(dar file) is also created based on the information that is present in the [manifest file](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/concept/xl-deploy-manifest-format.html#custom-deployment-package-support). There is no other extra settings for TFS XL Deploy task.

Comment: According to create package description `Creates a DAR archive **from the generated artifacts** and optionally outputs the ApplicationName as specified in the manifest. The DAR archive has the filename PackagePath. Specify the location of the generated artifacts by setting PackageDataRootPath. The manifest will be retrieved from ManifestPath. Values for placeholder replacement can be provided via the Dictionary parameter.` Seems could not be achieved. Question more related to xl-deploy side, you could confirm it through XL Deploy related support [here](https://docs.xebialabs.com/support.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an http or https url to fetch the artifact (next to the maven notation):
https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/how-to/add-an-externally-stored-artifact-to-a-package.html#use-an-http-or-https-uri